# Mapping MySqlDbType fields to MySQL keywords

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, database, visual-studio

**Problem:**

The MySQL.NET Connector has an enumeration called MySqlDbType which contains fields like Int16, Int32, Int64, Guid etc. Whilst I have not tested...something (gut feeling) tells me I cannot do this:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ID Guid NOT NULL, 
    Age Int32 NOT NULL
);
```

**Question:**

Does anyone know of a reference or list where each of the fields/values in MySqlDbType are mapped to their SQL keyword equivalent? Or shed some light on how I might specify column types using the enumeration when creating a table?

As a side note - some of these fields will use parameters, I will need knowledge of these too! i.e. VARCHAR(32) etc.

P.S. Sadly I am not a MySQL (or indeed SQL) expert!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [Numeric Data Types in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html) like `BIGINT, INT`:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    Age INT NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's getting closer to the answer...but what I really want is something aimed at .NET developers, like a list in the format of (E.G. Int64 = BIGINT) etc...